# "By" vs "with" vs "of"

Tags: grammar, prepositions

I came across a point of view that when you use "by" it means you are affected by the tool itself, whereas when you use "with" it would mean that you are affected by the actor's tool, like:

- "I was fascinated by his manners." - you were fascinated by the manner
  itself.
- "I was fascinated with his manners." - you were fascinated by him
  because of his manners, so he used his manners as a tool - "He
  fascinated me with his manners."
- "I was impressed by/with his speech" ...

Do you think it is appropriate in similar cases? Also, can we use "of" here?

"I was fascinated/impressed of his manners."

Comment: We usually use preposition ***by*** to connect a "verb of reaction" to the noun phrase ***causing*** that reaction. But not always - we're more likely to say [*I was **interested in his plan***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22was+interested+in+his+plan%22), for example (why ***by*** is a semi-valid" alternative, but ***with*** is a complete no-no). With your exact examples, ***with*** works better with ***impressed*** than ***fascinated***, but they're both at least "acceptable", whereas ***in*** doesn't work at all (and nor does ***of***).

Comment: Your point about *I was fascinated **with** his manners* implying that he deliberately *used* his mannerisms (as a "tool") to impress you is completely spurious. It's just a less common choice of preposition than ***by***. Consider *The building impressed me with its size,* where the building isn't doing *anything* "deliberately". ***With*** is an exceptionally broad-based preposition, with many different shades of meaning.

Comment: 'affected by the actor's tool'  oo-er missus!